# APDU for reading/writing ACOS3 card

Tags: smartcard, apdu

Reader: [ACR38U-H1](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/110/TSP-ACR38U-H1-6.07.pdfm=bv.104819420,d.bGg) ([reference manual](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/112/REF-ACR38x-CCID-6.05.pdf))
Card: [ACOS3-72K](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/FSP_ACOS3_v1%203.pdf).

Example of APDU string that works with my card: `80 84 00 00 08` (GET CHALLENGE). Answer is `AA630D0364AE54E5 9000`.

I'm trying to write data to a file via ADPU string `80 D0 00 01 05 AA BB CC DD EE`. The answer is `6985` (No currently selected EF, no command to monitor / no Transaction Manager File).

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my ADPU and how to write data correctly?

Comment: you have to first select the file.

Comment: Writing data to file sometimes require selection of file before sending write binary command in it if card contain any structure. 6985 i.e. Usage condition not satisfied. Hope you are missing something or study card detail first before sending command on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found in [ACR1222L API](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/API-ACR1222L-1.01.pdf) (it's not my card reader, but I found a lot of examples here).

Write file with name `55 55` (4 bytes of data - `01 02 03 04`, and yeah, I don't know really why I need so much APDU commands for this simple task):

```
80 20 07 00 08 41 43 4F 53 54 45 53 54
80 A4 00 00 02 FF 02
80 D2 00 00 04 00 00 01 00
80 A4 00 00 02 FF 04
80 D2 00 00 06 FF 01 00 00 55 55
80 A4 00 00 02 55 55
80 D2 00 00 04 01 02 03 04
```

Read file with name `55 55` (4 bytes):

```
80 B2 00 00 04
```

And also `FF 09 00 00 10` works fine too and shows some information about my reader.